# How to get the selective data from the array of nested objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, nested

I need the specific data from the input array. The input array is given below . and the excepted output array is given below using JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

I need to know what are the different ways to do that in JavaScript!

Using array methods or raw object and loops!

I need to know what is the efficient ways!

```js
const input = [
  {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    topLevelDomain: ['.af'],
    alpha2Code: 'AF',
    alpha3Code: 'AFG',
    callingCodes: ['93'],
    capital: 'Kabul',
    altSpellings: ['AF', 'Afġānistān'],
    region: 'Asia',
    subregion: 'Southern Asia',
    population: 27657145,
    latlng: [33, 65],
    demonym: 'Afghan',
    area: 652230,
    gini: 27.8,
    timezones: ['UTC+04:30'],
    borders: ['IRN', 'PAK', 'TKM', 'UZB', 'TJK', 'CHN'],
    nativeName: 'افغانستان',
    numericCode: '004',
    currencies: [
      {
        code: 'AFN',
        name: 'Afghan afghani',
        symbol: '؋'
      }
    ],
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: 'ps',
        iso639_2: 'pus',
        name: 'Pashto',
        nativeName: 'پښتو'
      },
      {
        iso639_1: 'uz',
        iso639_2: 'uzb',
        name: 'Uzbek',
        nativeName: 'Oʻzbek'
      },
      {
        iso639_1: 'tk',
        iso639_2: 'tuk',
        name: 'Turkmen',
        nativeName: 'Türkmen'
      }
    ],
    translations: {
      de: 'Afghanistan',
      es: 'Afganistán',
      fr: 'Afghanistan',
      ja: 'アフガニスタン',
      it: 'Afghanistan',
      br: 'Afeganistão',
      pt: 'Afeganistão',
      nl: 'Afghanistan',
      hr: 'Afganistan',
      fa: 'افغانستان'
    },
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg',
    regionalBlocs: [
      {
        acronym: 'SAARC',
        name: 'South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation',
        otherAcronyms: [],
        otherNames: []
      }
    ],
    cioc: 'AFG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Åland Islands',
    topLevelDomain: ['.ax'],
    alpha2Code: 'AX',
    alpha3Code: 'ALA',
    callingCodes: ['358'],
    capital: 'Mariehamn',
    altSpellings: ['AX', 'Aaland', 'Aland', 'Ahvenanmaa'],
    region: 'Europe',
    subregion: 'Northern Europe',
    population: 28875,
    latlng: [60.116667, 19.9],
    demonym: 'Ålandish',
    area: 1580,
    gini: null,
    timezones: ['UTC+02:00'],
    borders: [],
    nativeName: 'Åland',
    numericCode: '248',
    currencies: [
      {
        code: 'EUR',
        name: 'Euro',
        symbol: '€'
      }
    ],
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: 'sv',
        iso639_2: 'swe',
        name: 'Swedish',
        nativeName: 'svenska'
      }
    ],
    translations: {
      de: 'Åland',
      es: 'Alandia',
      fr: 'Åland',
      ja: 'オーランド諸島',
      it: 'Isole Aland',
      br: 'Ilhas de Aland',
      pt: 'Ilhas de Aland',
      nl: 'Ålandeilanden',
      hr: 'Ålandski otoci',
      fa: 'جزایر الند'
    },
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg',
    regionalBlocs: [
      {
        acronym: 'EU',
        name: 'European Union',
        otherAcronyms: [],
        otherNames: []
      }
    ],
    cioc: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Albania',
    topLevelDomain: ['.al'],
    alpha2Code: 'AL',
    alpha3Code: 'ALB',
    callingCodes: ['355'],
    capital: 'Tirana',
    altSpellings: ['AL', 'Shqipëri', 'Shqipëria', 'Shqipnia'],
    region: 'Europe',
    subregion: 'Southern Europe',
    population: 2886026,
    latlng: [41, 20],
    demonym: 'Albanian',
    area: 28748,
    gini: 34.5,
    timezones: ['UTC+01:00'],
    borders: ['MNE', 'GRC', 'MKD', 'KOS'],
    nativeName: 'Shqipëria',
    numericCode: '008',
    currencies: [
      {
        code: 'ALL',
        name: 'Albanian lek',
        symbol: 'L'
      }
    ],
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: 'sq',
        iso639_2: 'sqi',
        name: 'Albanian',
        nativeName: 'Shqip'
      }
    ],
    translations: {
      de: 'Albanien',
      es: 'Albania',
      fr: 'Albanie',
      ja: 'アルバニア',
      it: 'Albania',
      br: 'Albânia',
      pt: 'Albânia',
      nl: 'Albanië',
      hr: 'Albanija',
      fa: 'آلبانی'
    },
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg',
    regionalBlocs: [
      {
        acronym: 'CEFTA',
        name: 'Central European Free Trade Agreement',
        otherAcronyms: [],
        otherNames: []
      }
    ],
    cioc: 'ALB'
  }
];
```

and i need the output array like this

```js
const output = [
  {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    capital: 'Kabul',
    region: 'Asia',
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: 'ps',
        iso639_2: 'pus',
        name: 'Pashto',
        nativeName: 'پښتو'
      },
      {
        iso639_1: 'uz',
        iso639_2: 'uzb',
        name: 'Uzbek',
        nativeName: 'Oʻzbek'
      },
      {
        iso639_1: 'tk',
        iso639_2: 'tuk',
        name: 'Turkmen',
        nativeName: 'Türkmen'
      }
    ],
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Åland Islands',
    capital: 'Mariehamn',
    region: 'Europe',
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: 'sv',
        iso639_2: 'swe',
        name: 'Swedish',
        nativeName: 'svenska'
      }
    ],
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Albania',
    capital: 'Tirana',
    region: 'Europe',
    languages: [
      {
        iso639_1: 'sq',
        iso639_2: 'sqi',
        name: 'Albanian',
        nativeName: 'Shqip'
      }
    ],
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg'
  }
];
```

I have tried to get the specific values from the array of object but I can able to do it. The even complex array of object examples with answers also appreciated ! thank you.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Asking for different ways to do this is too broad.  You should be asking about a specific issue you are having with reaching your desired end goal.  People will then reply with what they think is the best approach.  You then get to pick which one is 'best' for you.

Comment: Iterate through the array with for of and create a new object with the desired properties.

Comment: @Taplar hey Taplar . i need anyone method is enough .thank you .

Comment: @FredericBrüning i did that but the result is like the values is consolelling like [object,object],[object,object]

Comment: @Taplar I need the solution for this please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript Array functions `map` and `reduce` to filter keys from input array. In the below example you can change the `outputKeys` array to get the wanted output.

```js
const outputKeys = ['name', 'capital', 'region', 'languages', 'flag'];

const output = input.map(item =>
  outputKeys.reduce((val, key) => ({ ...val, [key]: item[key] }), {})
);
```

Comment: its works ! thank you ! @baymax . in future im experting the various methods too from you and anyone else who is watching it !.